# php/javascript for calendar-start and date picker

Tags: php, javascript

I'm searching for php/javascript for calendar-start and date picker.
Based on these date i need to retrieve the database cash and bank amount details.

Answer (score 2):

Are you building a bank's online banking system? I would recommend highly scrutinizing any code you get off the internet if you are. Be wary of sites that host heaps of `snippets`, as there seems to be an abundance of lower quality code.

[jQuery's UI DatePicker is pretty good.](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker) A lot of people are also using it, so it is becoming a sort of standard. This is important, as if people recognise the DatePicker, they'll be more inclined to use it and already know how it functions.

Comment: I sure as hell hope someone programming a bank application isn't going around asking questions like this one...

Comment: That's what I thought Paolo!!

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is DatePicker from UI.jQuery - http://ui.jquery.com

Answer (score 0):

I've always like the Dynarch calendar:  http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/
It's what I've primarily used in the past.

I think the JQuery calendar is also a good choice.